# Using mutexes with detached threads in C

Tags: multithreading, mutex

```
#define SIZE 10

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

show(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int i = *(int *)arg;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

main()
{
    pthread_t threads[SIZE];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
        
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        assert(!pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, show, &i));
}
```

I've got a problem with passing value "i" to my detached threads. It should pass digits from 0 to 9 but it does not work like that. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no guarantee that a thread you start will immediately run and pick up the correct value of `i` from the pointer you pass to it. In the time it takes for the first thread to spin up, `main` could have gone through (for example) *five* iterations of the loop, updating `i` each time, meaning that the first thread will pick up some value greater than what it should be.

There are two possible solutions that come immediately to mind:

1. Make sure `main` pauses until the thread has started and picked up the correct value of `i`. This is messy since it involves some back-communication from the thread to `main` (such as condition variables).
2. Pass the `i` *value* in the pointer rather than a pointer to `i`. This ensures a local copy of that value is given to the thread rather than relying on a pointer to a possibly changing value.

---

The first option would go something like this, pseudo-code since I couldn't be bothered looking up the POSIX condition variable calls:

```
main:
    for i in 0..9:
        start thread passing address of i
        await condvar

thread recieving ptr:
    local i = contents of ptr
    kick condvar
    carry on
```

---

The second option is what I mostly see/do. You can change your thread creation call to something like:

```c
// Pass i-cast-to-a-pointer, rather than passing pointer-to-i.

assert(!pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, show, (void*)i));
```

and picking it up in the thread with:

```c
// Cast pointer back to int rather than dereferencing pointer.

int i = (int)arg;
```

---

As an aside, whether the thread is detached or not has no bearing here. This is a general race condition between threads.

Comment: By the way, after using condition variable calls  if I do some calculations in show function will they still be made at the same time in all threads?

Comment: @wixy0: the threads will still be concurrent, yes, at least as far as they can be (depends on cores, OS, etc). The condition variable is just used to stop `main` changing `i` until the thread has a local copy. So the `int i = *(int *)arg` cannot be concurrent, because `main` won't start the next thread until the previous thread has passed that point, but everything after the kicking of the condvar can be.

Comment: Another option is to have an array of `int`s, one for each thread to be started, and pass each thread a pointer to its own.